# Netlify throwing error when import/export modules, why?

Tags: javascript, continuous-deployment, es6-modules, netlify, netlify-cli

I have an API key hidden in a file, I'm not using dotenv to do this, and I'm importing them into my javascript file via ES6 modules. Netlify allows build commands to build this when the app is deployed.

`cd scripts && echo -e "const API_KEY = 'blahblahblah'; const HASH_KEY = 'blahblahblah'; const TIME_STAMP = 'ts=1'; const URL_ENDPOINT='blahblahblah';\n\nexport API_KEY, HASH_KEY, TIME_STAMP, URL_ENDPOINT;" > apikey.js`

That is what I put into Netlify's deploy settings.

When I go to the deployed site, I get `"Uncaught syntax error: unexpected token export".`

The file is made correctly in the sources tab of the console. I'm at a loss for what I've done incorrectly, or what Netlify isn't interpreting correctly.

Comment: Since you don't really show us much, all we can do is guess.  Typically, that error would be because nodejs is expecting a CommonJS module, but you are using ESM module syntax.  That could be because you have an old version of nodejs on the deployed site or because you don't have the right package.json that tells it this file should be an ESM module.  In a nuthsell, nodejs doesn't think you can use `export` in this file because it isn't treating it as an ESM module file.

Comment: I'm not using node though, just Vanilla JS...any clues on how to change that?

Comment: What do you mean vanilla JS?  You have to have some sort of Javascript engine to run your Javascript file.  The OS doesn't run JS files by itself.  There has to be some sort of Javascript environment that is in use.  It is that environment that is not happy here with the `export` word

Comment: I just meant that I didn't write backend code, just front-end and used api endpoints to pull data from the response. So, any clue how I could go about getting things to work correctly? My app doesn't have a package.json file.

Comment: Well, what exactly is the source of this error then?  Is this from your front-end Javascript?  I am massively confused now and have zero idea how to help as you basically just talk about an error, don't show any code, don't describe what code the error is coming from, etc...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else I can provide. The code itself isn't broken, it works. It's the deployment process that's not working.

Comment: Well, then you need to narrow down what step of the deployment process is having a problem.  If this is something that Netlify provides for you, then file a support issue with them.  It looks like whatever is trying to run or import `apikey.js` is not expecting an ESM module.  If that's Netlify's software, then go find out if they support ESM modules or if you need to use `module.exports` instead of the `export` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I was missing brackets in the build command, and after that I had to update some links from HTTP: to HTTPS:.

Thanks for trying to help out.